# Using Facebook Connect auth.RevokeAuthorization in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, api, facebook

I'm confused as to how revoking authorization works in the ASP.NET Toolkit.  I've tried issuing the following:

```
   ConnectSession connect = 
        new ConnectSession(FacebookHelper.ApiKey(), FacebookHelper.SecretKey());

   Auth x = new Auth(fbSession);
   x.RevokeAuthorization();
```

But I get an object reference error during the RevokeAuthorization call.  [Here's the call definition.](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Auth.revokeAuthorization)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a working example

```
   Facebook.Session.ConnectSession fbSession = 
                 new Facebook.Session.ConnectSession(ApiKey, SecretKey);
   fbSession.UserId = iFBUserID;
   fbSession.SessionKey = SessionKey;
   Api oApi = new Api(fbSession);
   oApi.Auth.RevokeAuthorization();
```

http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=50938